# EntityFrameworkCore Disable identity retrieval after insert

Tags: entity-framework-core

We have a `DbContext` (using MsSql). One of the DbSet has an entity containing an identity PK. When inserting a new entry, `SaveChanges()` automatically results in a select statement to retrieve the assigned ID (`SELECT [Id] ... WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity()`).

In most cases, this is great, or the overhead is minor. However, we also have an enpoint that just stores the data, thus, the assigned id doesn't matter to us - we `.Add(..)`, `.SaveChanges()` and `Dispose()` the context immidiately after.

For this specific endpoint, the overhead of the resulting select statement has a large impact. (due to some stuff not relevant to this question)

I cant seem to find how to turn this "Id retrieval"-mechanisme off, other then just writing the raw insert statements, or annotate ValueGeneratedNever. The first is not prefered for obvious reasons, the second will also change migrations and for all the 'normal' cases, it is fine how it is.

Can we turn this behavior off for 1 specific update / for 1 specific instanciated DbContext?

Comment: You can try using [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors). Theoretically, this way it is possible to change the generated SQL and interfere with the progress of the change tracker. But I doubt if it's worth it.

Comment: The use of extensions for mass insertion looks more promising. [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) - search for terms "bulk" and "batch".

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, it feels weird that it is impossible to turn it off in a 'normal' way, but thanks for your suggestions. I will give it a try. I would guess that interceptors then still have the downside of sending a database query (which i would then rewrite to just return a static value). Bulk might do indeed...

Comment: Ended up using SqlBulkCopy, for this specific case.

Comment: *it feels weird that it is impossible to turn it off in a 'normal' way* -- Why? I explained why it's conceptually impossible. If you'd do this by an interceptor the change tracker will scream.

Comment: Im not looking for an argument, but since you ask "why?" Because for just an insert, retrieving the Id has no use (afaik). I completely understand the need for the ID from a changetracker perspective, but if i just want to insert some data in the database and be done with it, I dont care about the assigned id. Kind of equivalent to '.AsNoTracking()' for retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

The Id retrieval is crucial for EF's change tracker and it can't be disabled. After saving, the entities get state `Unchanged` and `Unchanged` entities can't have default key values by design.

Try alternatives, like raw SQL. No other option.